# Can't run two queries in MariaDB sql server(syntax error) using Angular and Sequelize

Tags: mysql, angular, mariadb

I'm trying to delete from two different tables but I've got an error when tried to run the SQL command.
I'm trying to combine this two queries:

```
defaultAdapter.query('DELETE FROM reasons WHERE name = :name')
defaultAdapter.query('DELETE rt FROM reason_to_transaction rt INNER JOIN reasons r ON r.id = rt.reason_id WHERE name = :name')
```

I run this code:

```
defaultAdapter.query('DELETE FROM reasons WHERE name = :name;DELETE rt, r FROM reason_to_transaction rt INNER JOIN reasons r ON r.id = rt.reason_id WHERE id = :id',
```

Could someone tell me what is the right syntax for 2 queries in Sequelize method(SQL).
When I run this command I've got this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE rt, r FROM reason_to_transaction rt INNER JOIN reasons r ON r.id = rt.rea' at line 1
    at Query.formatError
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not allow you to combine two queries into one call.

If you need them tied together in a single "transaction" (all or none), then you need some form of `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`.